# Covering a Lie group with balls of radius $\epsilon$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, volume, isometry

Suppose $G$ is a compact lie group with a bi-invariant metric (a metric under which multiplications from right and left are isometries). How can one show that there is a uniform $C>0$ so that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $G$ can be covered with at most $\left\lceil C\dfrac{\text{Vol}(G)}{\epsilon^d}\right\rceil$ balls?

Comment: One possible starting point: Can you find such a $C$ for a ball of radius $r$ in hyperbolic space?

Comment: Sadly, I've just very recently finished reading riemannian geometry. I'm afraid I'm not really used to the hyperbolic space. However, is the hyperbolic space a lie group? Sorry if I'm asking something silly. It might be with these matrix representations but as I said, I'm really not familiar with it much.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is true of all compact Riemannian manifolds, so a Lie group structure isn't necessary. The idea is that the curvature of $G$ has a lower bound $K$, so there are [some comparison theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toponogov%27s_theorem) which allow you to find [short maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_map) from a $r$-ball in the curvature model space $M_k$ to any $r$-ball in $G$ (for some uniform small $r$) If you can solve the problem in $M_k$ (i.e. hyperbolic space), then these maps allow you to construct a solution in $G$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. For the Lie group, after talking to a friend of mine Hesam, we found a solution. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Lie groups, we can use the $3r$-covering Lemma in real analysis. Since the metric is bi-invariant, all balls of the same radius have the same volume (this is the use of the fact that we have a lie group). Now, the $3r$-covering lemma works for every metric space. If we use it here on a finite sub-covering of balls $\left\{B_{\epsilon/3}(g)\right\}_{g \in G}$ like ${B_\epsilon/3(g_1), B_\epsilon/3(g_2), ..., B_\epsilon/3(g_n)}$, then there are disjoint balls $B_{\epsilon/3}(g_{i_1}), B_{\epsilon/3}(g_{i_2}), ..., B_{\epsilon/3}(g_{i_k})$ where $1 \le i_1, ..., i_k \le n$, so that after making those balls 3 times fater, $G$ is covered. Now the idea of having disjoint balls is that, when we don't allow intersection, we have a bound like $\left\lceil\dfrac{Vol(G)}{Vol(B_{\epsilon/3}(e))}\right\rceil$ on their cardinality. This now gives the assymptotic bound.

(The core idea of the solution is by my friend Hesam.)

Comment: Sorry I might be off here, but I would like to know how is the ball $B_\epsilon (g)$  defined ?

Comment: With the help of the Riemannian metric $D$, the lie group is also a metric space as well. So we can make sense of it in the metric sense.

Comment: I know that  $G$ is a metric space; which means that each of its tangent spaces is a metric space. So my question is if  we have $g \in G$ and $\epsilon >0$ what is the definition of the ball $B_\epsilon(g)$ using metrics on tangent spaces of $G$ ?

Comment: The riemannian metric defines an inner product on each tangent space. Using that inner product you can define an actual metric on your manifold by defining lengths of curves so that taking the curves with minimum length between points also gives their distance in this metric. Check for example John M. Lee, Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know about this definition. thank you so much for the clarification, and  thanks for the reference .